# Minimum value in an array is always set to 0

Tags: java, arrays

I am new to Java and when I want to input integers into an array and then output the lowest and highest value, the lowest is always 0 even when I don't input 0.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Arrays {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int array[] = new int[10];
        int max = array[0], min = array[0];
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++) {
            array[i] = input.nextInt();

                if(array[i]>max) 
                    max = array[i];

                if(array[i]<min) 
                    min = array[i];
        }

        for ( int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++)
            System.out.println(array[i]);

        System.out.printf("The lowest number is %d"
                + " and the highest number is %d",min,max);
    }
```

Could someone please tell me where my error is and why is that?

Comment: Because You are initializing `min` with `array[0]` which is default initialized to 0. Initialize `min` with some big number like `Integer::MAX_VALUE`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is here:

```
int max = array[0], min = array[0];
```

You initialize `max` and `min` to `0`, since at this point the array contains only `0`s by default (since you haven't assigned values to it yet). Therefore, if all the inputs are positive, `min` will remain `0`.

To overcome that issue, you might want to first read all the inputs into the array, and use a second loop to find the minimum and maximum values.

Another alternative would be to initialize `max` to `Integer.MIN_VALUE` and `min` to `Integer.MAX_VALUE`.

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the help and for taking our time to help me.